# Netem effects on which factors of net

Tags: linux, networking

I am downloading files from other sources, for testing purpose I am using `netem` to make delay while downloading the files. Its working fine, but I want to know on which factors of internet it(`netem`) effects. I mean it applies delay on `Bandwidth` or `Download-Time` or any `connection related properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding delay through NetEm, the packets' latency is increased. This comes to simulate slow/long network, e.g. long physical lines and/or a lot of switches in the way to the end point. Long latency might cause a slow down in bandwidth, especially for TCP traffic, since it increases the chance for retransmits due to timeouts.
Since download time = file size / bandwidth, you can argue they are one and the same. If the added delay that causes long latency would also cause a degradation in average bandwidth, you'll experience longer download time.
I suggest to first check the latency before and after applying the delay. You should expect an increase equals to the introduced delay (or 2 * delay for round-trip latency).

Comment: How can I check latency in linux

Comment: I usually use netperf with the -t TCP_RR or -t UDP_RR flags. See example here: https://www.clustermonkey.net/Cluster-Newbie/measuring-network-performance/Page-2.html. qperf can also be used (less familiar with it): https://www.opsdash.com/blog/network-performance-linux.html. Both tools report transactions per second which can be translated to (average latency) = 1/(transactions per second). qperf also provides round trip latency by default.